# MediaPlayer error (1, -1004) while playing stream via internet

Tags: android, media-player

There is audio player that is playing some audio file via http protocol in my app.

Problem is that mp3 is playing normally when program is connected with server via lan and it is not working via internet and throw exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
```

1. chrome browser can open link and play.
2. other services working fine.

Logcat shows:

```
error (1, -1004)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had that same error because I enabled iptables, the linux firewall, in a rooted device using droidwall. What I discovered was that if my app was allowed to get access to internet but the process "Media Server" did't, I got the 1004 error during "prepare".

If this is your case disabling iptables or adding a rule for Media Server will work.